# Posets isomorphic to their endomorphism poset

Tags: order-theory, posets

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset. We set $$\text{End}(P)=\{f: P\to P: f\text{ is order-preserving}\}$$ and order $\text{End}(P)$ pointwise.

Is there a poset with more than 1 point such that $P\cong \text{End}(P)$?

Comment: Not, if I understand your question right (non-strict order preserving). You always have constant maps, as many as elements in the set, **plus** at least the identity.

Comment: Your argument is correct for finite posets, but you still have to look at infinite posets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $P$ is infinite and $P\cong \textrm{End}(P)$, then the size of
$P$ is restricted by the following facts.

Lemma. Assume that $P$ is an infinite poset.

1. $P$ has an infinite antichain, an infinite well-ordered subset,
   or an infinite inversely well-ordered subset.
2. If $|P|>2^{\lambda}$ for some infinite $\lambda$, then $P$ has an antichain, a well-ordered subset,
   or an inversely well-ordered subset of size $>\lambda$.
3. If $P$ has an antichain of size at least $\kappa\geq\omega$, then $\textrm{End}(P)$
   has an antichain of size at least $2^{\kappa}$.
4. If $P$ has a well-ordered or inversely well-ordered subset
   of size at least $\kappa\geq\omega$, then $\textrm{End}(P)$
   has an antichain of size at least $2^{\kappa}$.

In particular, these facts imply that if $P\cong \textrm{End}(P)$,
then $|P|\geq \beth_{\omega}$. If also 
$|P|>2^{\lambda}$ for some infinite $\lambda$, then $|P|>2^{2^{\lambda}}$.

Sketch of proofs.

Part 1 of the Lemma follows from Ramsey's Theorem.

Part 2 of the Lemma follows from the Erdos-Rado Theorem.

For part 3 of the Lemma, if $P$ is an antichain, then $\textrm{End}(P)$
is an antichain of size $2^{|P|}$, so the claim is clear. Otherwise
choose $a<b$ in $P$. Let $A\subseteq P$ be an antichain in $P$
of cardinality $\kappa$. It is possible to find a set
$\mathcal X$ of pairwise incomparable subsets of $A$ such that
$|\mathcal X|=2^{\kappa}$. For each $U\in \mathcal X$
define $f_U\colon P\to P$ by $f_U(x)=b$ if $x$ is in the
filter generated by $U$ in $P$, else $f_U(x)=a$.
The set $\{f_U | U\in \mathcal X\}$ is an antichain of size
$2^{\kappa}$ in $\textrm{End}(P)$.

For part 4 of the lemma, assume that 
$W = \{w_{\alpha} : \alpha < \kappa\}$ is an enumeration of
an increasing $\kappa$-sequence in $P$.
Define a partial function $\sigma\colon P\to P$ by taking
$\sigma(x)$ to be the least element $w_{\alpha}$ in $W$
such that $x\not\geq w_{\alpha}$. This $\sigma$ is a monotone total
function if $W$ is cofinal in $P$, but only a partial function
if there is some $q\in P$ above every $w_{\alpha}$. If such $q$
exists, fix one such, and extend the definition of $W$ to include $w_{\kappa}=q$
and extend the definition of $\sigma$ so that $\sigma(x)=q$
if $x\geq w_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$. Either way, $W$
is well-ordered, of size $\kappa$, and $\sigma\in \textrm{End}(P)$
maps $P$ into $W$ and $\sigma(P)$ is well-ordered and of size $\kappa$.
(Note: $\sigma(P)$ might be a proper subset of $W$.)

For every subset $V\subseteq \sigma(P)$ not containing $w_{\kappa}$
define $g\colon \sigma(P)\to \sigma(P)$ by $g(w_{\alpha})=w_{\alpha}$
if $w_{\alpha}\in \sigma(P)\setminus V$ and
$g(w_{\alpha})=w_{\alpha+1}$
if $w_{\alpha}\in V$. If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are incomparable subsets
of $\sigma(P)$, then $g_{V_1}$ and $g_{V_2}$ are incomparable elements
of $\textrm{End}(P)$. There is a set
of $2^{\kappa}$-many pairwise incomparable
subsets of the $\kappa$-element set $\sigma(P)\setminus\{w_{\kappa}\}$,
so $\textrm{End}(P)$ has an antichain
of size at least $2^{\kappa}$. \\

Comment: I must also mention that if $\mu$ is the strong limit cardinal with $\mu\leq|P|\leq 2^{\mu}$, then $\mu$ is not a weakly compact cardinal since if $\mu\rightarrow(\mu)^{2}_{3}$, then $|P|$ would have a well-ordered or anti-well ordered chain or an antichain of cardinality $\mu$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: For my own sanity: under GCH, what we conclude is that $|P|$ is uncountable, and is either a limit cardinal or the successor of a limit cardinal.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to

> Is there a poset with more than 1 point such that $P\cong\text{End}(P)$?

is No. This follows immediately from Theorem 3 in

> [Roy O. Davies, Allan Hayes and George Rousseau, Complete lattices and the generalized Cantor theorem, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 27 (1971), 253–258](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-02/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0.pdf).

This reference was pointed out to me by user [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof) in a (now deleted) comment to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302516/660). More precisely bof gave a link to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064374/660) of them.

Answer (score 4):

By Keith Kearnes answer, there is a strong limit cardinal $\mu$ such that $\mu\leq|P|\leq 2^{\mu}$. I claim that if $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra and $e:P\rightarrow B$ is an order preserving mapping with $e[P]$ dense in $B$, then $|B|<\mu$. Suppose to the contrary that $|B|\geq\mu$. Then by the [Balcar-franek theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-274-02/S0002-9947-1982-0675069-3/S0002-9947-1982-0675069-3.pdf), there is a subalgebra $A\subseteq B$ with $|A|=|B|$ that is freely generated by some set $F$. Let $r,s\in P,r<s$. For each $a\in F$, let $\ell_{a}(x)=r$ whenever $e(x)\leq a$ and $\ell_{a}(x)=s$ otherwise. Then $(\ell_{a})_{a\in F}$ is an antichain in $P$ of cardinality $\mu$ which contradicts Keith Kearnes' answer. In particular, the poset $P$ is not separative, nor is its dual separative. Furthermore, if $Q\subseteq P$ and $|Q|\geq\mu$, then $Q$ is not separative nor dual separative and there cannot be an order preserving mapping $e:Q\rightarrow B$ where $e[Q]$ is dense in $B$ and $|B|\geq\mu$.