# If $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal C$, is $\mathcal C$ necessarily equivalent to a category with one object and one morphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category which is equivalent to the category $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ of its endofunctors.

> Is $\mathcal C$ necessarily equivalent to a category having exactly one object and one morphism?

A particular case of this question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211489/461).

Comment: I do not know the answer in the case that the ambient theory is classical set theory, but it is possible to arrange an intuitionistic set theory in which there is a non-trivial set $D$ such that $D \cong D^D$, which would then give you an example (take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the discrete category on $D$). If anyone can answer your question positively, they will have to use excluded middle or choice.

Comment: I can also produce a counter-example if $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{C}$ is replaced with the category of endofunctors that preserve filtered colimits. In this case we can find a poset which will do the job.

Comment: @AndrejBauer - The setting I had in mind was ZFC (possibly with universes), but I'm open to other settings. I'd be very happy if you posted your answer. (I won't promise that I would accept it, even if, I'm sure, it would be correct and highly interesting!)

Comment: Note that there is a canonical fully faithful functor $const: C \to C^{C}$ sending an object to the constant functor at that object. Moreover, if $C$ is not the terminal category, then the identity functor is not in the essential image of $const$. So if $F: C \to C^{C}$ is an equivalence, then $F^{-1} \circ const: C \to C$ is a fully faithful endofunctor which is not essentially surjective. This rules out, for example, categories with finitely many isomorphism classes of objects. At a more basic level, $C^{C}$ is monoidal under composition, so any such $C$ must be monoidal.

Comment: This is an interesting tweak to your [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/333902) from last week. I thought about trying to let $D=C^C$ from my answer there, but it doesn't work because the set of objects of $D^D$ has cardinality $End(G)^{End(G)}$, while the set of objects of $D$ has cardinality $End(G)$.

Comment: In fact, here's a related question: if $C$ has more than one isomorphism class of objects, does $C^C$ have to have strictly more isomorphism classes of objects than $C$?

Comment: @MattFeller - About your 2nd comment: I was planning to ask this question next week, unless somebody found a nontrivial example with $C^C\sim C$, but now I think that **you** should ask the question if you feel like doing it. (I also considered adding it to the present question, but I thought then I wouldn't know if I should accept an answer answering one of the 2 questions.) (An intermediate question would be: are there nontrivial examples of categories $C_1,...,C_n$ with $C_{i+1}=C_i^{C_i}$ for $i=1,...,n-1$ and $C_1\sim C_n$?)

Comment: @MattFeller - You may want to take a look at my comment to the post https://mathoverflow.net/a/211521/461

Comment: Another small observation: any such $C$ must be _connected_. For if $C$ has $\kappa$ many connected components, then $C^C$ has at least $\kappa^\kappa$ many connected components, and the only $\kappa$ such that $\kappa = \kappa^\kappa$ is $\kappa = 1$. Since the identity is connected to the constant functors, there is even a bound on the length of zigzag needed to get from one object to another.

Comment: I think I can prove that $\mathsf{C}$ cannot be a large locally presentable category, is it of any interest?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti - It looks highly interesting to me!

Comment: The general idea is already encoded in the fact that $\mathsf{C}$ cannot be a presheaf category. In fact in a presheaf category there is only a set of tiny objects, while if $\mathsf{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{Psh}(\mathsf{D})$, then $\mathsf{C}^\mathsf{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{Psh}(\mathsf{Psh}(\mathsf{D}) \times \mathsf{D})$, which has a proper class of tiny objects (the image of the Yoneda embedding). Tiny objects are preserved by equivalences. A very similar argument can be played replacing tiny objects with $\lambda$-presentables.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti - Thanks! I think that, if you posted an answer, you could explain your arguments in a more convenient and detailed way. This would also give more visibility to your idea.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a constraint of a different nature from the ones mentioned so far in the comments. I work in ZFC with one universe $V_\kappa =: Set$. Let $CARD$ denote the class of cardinals $<\kappa$. Below all arithmetic is cardinal arithmetic (not ordinal arithmetic).

**Proposition:** Let $\mathcal C$ be a category with $\mathcal C \simeq \mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$. Assume that

- The number of isomorphism classes of objects of $\mathcal C$ is $< 2^\kappa$
- $\mathcal C$ is locally small (its homsets are of size $<\kappa$)
- $\mathcal C$ has all small [powers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power) *and* all small [copowers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower).

Then $\mathcal C$ is a preorder.

**Remarks:**

- There are two important cases where $\mathcal C$ has all small powers and all small copowers:

  1. if $\mathcal C$ has all small products and all small coproducts.
  2. if $\mathcal C$ is a preorder

  So the proposition could be stated as an "if and only if".
- Of course, the existence of the powers and copowers should be viewed as the"substantive" hypothesis, and the size restrictions as "technical".
- I think these hypotheses are general enough to make the case that no "nice large category" satisfies $\mathcal C \simeq \mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$, but of course it would be interesting to weaken the hypothesis. That would probably require quite different methods not reducing to the existence of lots of $Set$-functors as below. There's [another paper of Koubek](https://eudml.org/doc/16542) on *contravariant* $Set$-functors, which might allow one to assume only the existence of powers without assuming the existence of copowers (or dually).

**Proof:**
For any $F: Set \to Set$, and $A \in \mathcal C$, we may form a functor $\Phi_{F,A}: \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$, $C \mapsto \amalg_{x \in F(\mathcal C(A,C))} A$. Suppose for contradiction that $\mathcal C$ is not a preorder. Fix $A,B$ such that

$$\lambda := |\mathcal C(A,B)| \geq 2$$

Let $\mathcal A$ be the class of (small) cardinals of the form $\alpha = \lambda^\mu$, and let $\mathcal F$ be the class of all weakly increasing functions $f: \mathcal A \to CARD$ such that

1. $f(\alpha) \geq 2^\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal A$.
2. For all $\alpha \in \mathcal A$, if $\lambda^{f(\alpha)} = \lambda^\beta$, then $f(\alpha) \leq \beta$.

Clearly $|\mathcal F| = 2^\kappa$. By a [theorem of Koubek](https://eudml.org/doc/16420) [1], for every $f \in \mathcal F$, there is a functor  $F_f: Set \to Set$ with $|F_f(X)| = f(|X|)$ for all $X$ with $|X| \in \mathcal A$. Because $\mathcal C$, and hence $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$, has only $< 2^\kappa$ many isomorphism classes of objects, there are $f_1 \neq f_2 \in \mathcal F$ such that $\Phi_{F_1,A} \cong \Phi_{F_2,A}$ (where $F_i = F_{f_i}$).  Since $f_1 \neq f_2$, there is a cardinal $\mu$ such that $f_1(\lambda^\mu) \neq f_2(\lambda^\mu)$. We have that $\Phi_{F_1,A}(\prod_\mu B) \cong\Phi_{F_2,A}(\prod_\mu B)$, i.e. $\amalg_{f_1(\lambda^\mu)} A \cong \amalg_{f_2(\lambda^\mu)} A$. Homming into $B$, we find that $\mathcal C(A,B)^{f_1(\lambda^\mu)} \cong \mathcal C(A,B)^{f_2(\lambda^\mu)}$. But by the second condition in the definition of $\mathcal F$, this implies that $f_1(\lambda^\mu) = f_2(\lambda^\mu)$, contradicting the choice of $\mu$.

[1] Koubek, Václav. "Set functors." Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae 012.1 (1971): 175-195. http://eudml.org/doc/16420, Prop 2.4, bottom of p. 183 (p.10 of the pdf) -- note that bizarrely in this paper that means section 4, second proposition, and is also different from Lemma 2.4.

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer. I tried to mimic the proof of Theorem 3 in

[1] [Complete lattices and the generalized Cantor theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-027-02/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0/S0002-9939-1971-0268091-0.pdf) by Roy O. Davies, Allan Hayes and George Rousseau, published in *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 27 (1971), 253–258.

(The notation used in this answer is different from the one in the question. I'll stick as much as possible to the notation and terminology of [1].)

All categories in this post are small.

Let $A$ and $B$ be categories, and let $b_0,b_1$ be two objects of $B$ such that there is a morphism $b_0\to b_1$ but no morphism $b_1\to b_0$.

We claim

(1) $B^B$ is not equivalent to $B$,

(2) there is no full functor $B^A\to A$ and no essentially surjective functor $A\to B^A$.

It suffices to prove (2).

For any category $C$ write $C_0$ for the set of objects of $C$.

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories. Say that a map $F:C_0\to D_0$ is a **weak monomorphism** if the existence of morphisms $c\to c'$ and $F(c')\to F(c)$ implies that of a morphism $c'\to c$.

It is clear that the map $C_0\to D_0$ induced by a full functor is a weak monomorphism. It is also clear that the existence of an essentially surjective functor  $D\to C$ implies that of a weak monomorphism $C_0\to D_0$.

We claim

(3) There is no weak monomorphism $(B^A)_0\to A_0$.

It suffices to prove (3).

Let $2$ be the ordinal $\{0,1\}$ viewed as a category. We claim

(4) There is no weak monomorphism $(2^A)_0\to A_0$.

Let us show that (4) implies (3).

Let $F:(B^A)_0\to A_0$ be a weak monomorphism, let $J:2\to B$ be a functor mapping $i$ to $b_i$ for $i=0,1$ (such a functor exists by assumption), and define $F':(2^A)_0\to A_0$ by $F'(G):=F(J\circ G)$. It is straightforward to check (using the assumption that there is no morphism $b_1\to b_0$) that $F'$ is a weak monomorphism (details left to the reader). This proves that (4) implies (3).

It suffices to prove (4).

Say that a subset $R$ of $A_0$ is a **right ideal** if the conditions $a\in R$ and there is a morphism $a\to a'$ imply $a'\in R$. The right ideals form a complete lattice $\mathcal R$ order isomorphic to $(2^A)_0$. (The order on $\mathcal R$ is given by inclusion.)

Thus it suffices to show that there is no weak monomorphism $\mathcal R\to A_0$.

Let $\phi:\mathcal R\to A_0$ be a map. Define the map $f:\mathcal R\to \mathcal R$ by letting $f(R)$ be the right ideal generated by $\phi(R)$. By the corollary to Theorem 1 in [1] there is an $R$ in $\mathcal R$ such that 
$$
f(R)\le\bigcup_{S>R}f(S).
$$ 
As we have $\phi(R)\in f(R)$, this implies $\phi(R)\in f(S)$ for some $S$ in $\mathcal R$ with

(5) $R<S$,

and thus (by definition of $f(S)$) the existence of a morphism

(6) $\phi(S)\to\phi(R)$.

Now (5) and (6) imply that $\phi$ is not a weak monomorphism.

Comment: Suppose that $C \simeq C^C$. By my observation [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334266/if-mathcal-c-mathcal-c-is-equivalent-to-mathcal-c-is-mathcal-c-nece?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment835294_334266), $C$ is connected. In particular, there is a zigzag of natural transformations between $id_C$ and $const_c$ for your favorite object $c \in C$. By your (1), the zigzag can be converted into natural transformations $id_C \to const_c \to id_C$, which means that $C$ has _zero morphisms_, i.e. an enrichment in pointed sets.

Comment: Conversely, the fact that $C$ has zero morphisms implies your (1).