# Category with few endofunctors?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category whose skeleton has $\lambda$-many objects and $\kappa$-many morphisms. Then the skeleton of the endofunctor category $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ has at most $\kappa^{3 \times \kappa}$ many morphisms.

My guess is that in most cases, this upper bound is achieved.

**Question:** What is an example of a category $\mathcal C$ (other than the terminal category or equivalents) whose skeleton has $\lambda$ many objects and $\kappa$ many morphisms, but the skeleton of whose endofunctor category $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ has

1. *Strictly fewer* than $\kappa^\kappa$ many morphisms?
2. *Strictly fewer* than $\kappa^\kappa$ many objects?
3. As few as $\kappa$-many morphisms?
4. As few as $\lambda$-many objects?

**EDIT:** Neil Strickland's example of $B\mathbb N$ in the comments below affirmatively answers (1), (2), and (3). So it remains to see about (4).

Note that $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ always has (skeletally) at least $\lambda+1$ many objects and $\kappa+1$-many morphisms, given by constant morphisms between constant endofunctors, along with the identity functor.

Note also that if $\mathcal C$ is accessible, and has as many objects and morphisms as the size of the universe, then the number of *accessible* endofunctors and morphisms between them is also the size of the universe. So if my guess is correct, then *most* endofunctors are usually non accessible.

See also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334266/if-mathcal-c-mathcal-c-is-equivalent-to-mathcal-c-is-mathcal-c-nece/334962#334962) for an argument which shows that if $\mathcal C$ has small products and coproducts and is not a preorder, then $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ has (skeletally) at least $2^\kappa$-many objects, where $\kappa$ is the size of the universe.

Comment: A directed graph?

Comment: "Skeleton" up to natural isomorphism or natural equivalence? It probably does not matter. And another thought: should we not be looking at objects up to isomorphism, or at least count objects in the skeleton of $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Why is $\kappa^\lambda$ an upper bound? If $\lambda$ is 1 it seems like there can be more than $\kappa$ many morphisms (indeed $\kappa+1>\kappa$ if $\kappa$ is finite)

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole fixed, thanks

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don’t understand— we’re talking about 1-categories so there’s only one notion of isomorphism. And I thought I did say to take the skeleton before any relevant cardinality counts.

Comment: @MarkSapir I’m not sure what you’re suggesting but the free category on a directed graph can have more endofunctors than objects. Consider the finite cardinals for instance.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the first occurrence of "skeleton".

Comment: What if $\mathcal{C}$ is $\mathbb{N}$, considered as a category with one object?  Then $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{C}}$ is equivalent to the discrete category with objects $\mathbb{N}$, so both $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{C}}$ have countably many morphisms.

Comment: @TimCampion: You want an example. I suggested that some graph may be an example. Of course, not **any graph**.

Comment: @TimCampion maybe I'm miscalculating, but I think for $\mathcal{C}$ the one object category with a single nontrivial idempotent, $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{C}}$ has two objects (the identity and the constant functor) and six morphisms (two identities and 4 non-isomorphisms, each with component the idempotent).

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Thanks again. I now believe the correct thing to say is that a morphism in $\mathcal C^{\mathcal C}$ is a functor $[1] \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$, so the number thereof is bounded by $\kappa^{\kappa'}$ where $\kappa' = 3 \times \kappa$ is the number of morphisms in $[1] \times \mathcal C$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thanks, I think that answers most of my questions!

Comment: @MarkSapir Thanks, I'm still not sure what you're proposing. Every category has an underlying directed graph, so I'm continuing to guess that you mean to take the free category on a directed graph. Could you say something about why you think such a category might be constructed to have few endofunctors? I'm not seeing it right now.

Comment: Endofunctors for graphs are endomorphisms. It is easy to create graphs with weird endomorphism semigroups.

Comment: Yes. Constructing such graphs is an exercise.

Comment: @MarkSapir I believe you when you say that graphs with weird endomorphism monoids can be constructed. But a graph is not a category— most graphs don’t admit even one category structure! You can always take the free category on a graph, but it seems this will generally make the endomorphism monoid grow. So unless you can clarify further, I really don’t understand your suggestion.

Comment: Yes take the free category.

Comment: Take a bipartite directed graph where all edges go from part $A$ to part $B$. The free category is not much different from the graph. You add constant endomorphisms, that is it.

Comment: @MarkSapir I see -- you're suggesting using a bipartite graph admitting a surjective homomorphism to the arrow category. After a bit of thought, I think I've convinced myself that if such a graph is countably infinite, then it admits at least continuum-many endomorphisms, so unfortunately doesn't fit the bill here. I haven't carefully thought through the case of higher cardinalities, but I'm a bit pessimistic.

Comment: I do not know what an arrow category is and why it came up here. If my suggestion does not work, its ok with me.

Comment: @HarryWest That's beautiful, and really deserves to be an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of (1),(2),(3),(4) with $\kappa=\lambda=|\mathbb R|$ is to take $\mathcal C$ to be the posetal category $\mathbb R.$ This is already skeletal. Its category of endofunctors is the poset of non-decreasing functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ with the pointwise order. There are at most $|\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}|=|\mathbb R|$ such functions: $f$ is determined by the preimages $f^{-1}((-\infty,q))$ for $q\in\mathbb Q,$ each of these intervals is convex, and there are at most $|\mathbb R|$ convex subsets of $\mathbb R.$

(I don't know if there are, unconditionally, examples with $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ regular. I think the $\mathbb R$ example generalizes to $2^\mu$ with the lex order, where $\mu$ is an ordinal satisfying $|2^{2^{<\mu}}|=|2^\mu|,$ for example $\mu=\beth_\alpha$ with $\alpha$ a limit ordinal. Here $2^{<\mu}$ means the functions $\mu\to 2$ with bounded support.)